# Error in textscan

Tags: matlab, text

I want to import kddcup dataset in matlab. When I import this dataset:

```
fid = fopen('kddcup.testdata','rt');
data = textscan(fid,['%d %s %s %s ', repmat('%f ',1,37), '%s'], 'delimiter',',');
fclose(fid);
```

And I get this error:

> Error using textscan
>   Invalid file identifier.  Use fopen to generate a valid file identifier.

What is wrong in this code?

Comment: what is the extension `.testdata`? Is this the extension of the file?

Comment: No, ".testdata" is not the extension. It is just a file name .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that Matlab doesn't find the file you specify.

Note that you should type a full name, including the extension (e.g. `'myfile.txt'`) and make sure it's in your current directory (otherwise, you have to write the full path).

If you call `fopen` correctly, then `fid` should have an integer number, otherwise it returns `-1`. You should chek that too.

Comment: I try full name with extension and it is worked . Thank you